# Why tomcat is dependent on wi-fi

Tags: android, tomcat, wifi

I am developing a sample application on GCM (Android). In it I am using tomcat server to send the message. and a device which receives the message. Every thing works fine, unless my wifi turns off. Once my wi-fi turns off, I stop getting message to my device and on browser I get following error. Can any body tell what's the connection between wifi and GCM service.?

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.net.UnknownHostException: android.googleapis.com
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:479)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:458)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.33 logs.
```

For any more clarification feel free to ask!!

Comment: wouldn't it be better, if you copied the stacktrace and pasted here, than putting a snap shot?

Comment: Done RJ. I guess its more readable now

Comment: Your server can no longer contact the Google GCM server. Is it probably conneted to the Internet via the same WiFi network?

Comment: @Henry. Yes its connected to internet via same WiFi network. Still any detail description about the same??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a notification is sent, it first goes from your server to the Google GCM server and then from the GCM server to the phone. Both links must be up and running for the notification to arrive.

It seems you have disrupted the connection from your server to the internet when you brought down WiFi. It is no longer able to connect to the Google server.

Comment: Hey thanks Henry for simple word explanation . Got it. Now both of you answered correctly, which one to accept. Should I post another question in meta to ask this, lol :D

Comment: One more thing. Why when I am connected to internet through LAN cable. and try to register my device, I am not able to register?

Comment: This is probably worth another question. Include enough details: What error did you get? Which part of the registration failed (phone to Google server, or phone to your server) ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should show you an error.

Reason : I am assuming that you are accessing GSM Services using local network connection. So your device/phone is expecting your WiFi Connection to be on.

Comment: Can u explain a bit plzzz. or any link or doc to support the answer. Its not clear to me!!!

Comment: You are accessing GCM Service using Wifi Connection in Phone, right ?

Comment: yes. and also I am connected to my device via data cable. So why does it make use of that??

Comment: I think cable connection is just for transfering .apk file. You can not access GSM Service using USB Cable.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Huskar but still I am not clear about the whole concept. How webservice will be able to connect to my device as I will not be using Tomcat Server all the time. Can u explain the whole phenomenon to me. or DOC.